# I'm trying to install Sublime Text 2 on my Ubuntu machine

Tags: sublime-text

I have downloaded the 64bit executable Sublime Text file and have extracted it. It then created a subdirectory called Sublime Text 2. I can see because I've done an `ls`.

The problem is when I do `cd Sublime Text 2`, I get:

```
-bash: cd: Sublime: No such file or directory.
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm a newbie at Linux!

Answer (score 1):

Linux isn't very friendly with spaces in file names. In the old days, operating systems couldn't support spaces in file names and spaces in file names can be problematic when programming.

In the command line, a space in a file name is equal to a backslash then a space.

For example, to go to Sublime directory, you would type:

```
cd Sublime\ Text\ 2/
```

Comment: You could also surround the command with double quotes.